# Is it a clean way to implement a kind of "__tuple__" method?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let that an object a of a class A has an attribute ".my_tuple".
I want to be able to get this attribute calling.

```
tuple(a)
```

the simplier way I found is to define A such as:

```
class A():
    # other things
    def __iter__(self):
        return self.my_tuple.__iter__()
```

But it seems a little dirty : what I understand is that "tuple(a)" will iterate over self.my_tuple in order to construct a copy of it, while I only want a pointer on it... Is the built-in "tuple" optimized to deal with those cases ? If not, is it a best way to do that (an keep it "pythonic" : in my case it make sense to cast A-type into tuple).

Comment: If you really want a pointer, or a reference in Pythonic tongue, why not just call `a.my_tuple`. tuple in its nature is immutable, I think

Comment: The situation is not exactly what I've described : I have several attributes for instance a.b, a.c, a.d and I would like to be able to do tuple(a) to get (b,c,d). I could add a mehod a.tuple() which do the staff, but it does not look pythonic to me.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Your question sounds like you have an attribute that already is a tuple, and you do want to create an unnecessary copy of that tuple. Now you say that you want the tuple to hold the content of several (all?) the attributes of the class. Please clarify.

Comment: And because it's immutable the shortcut of just returning the the input, instead of iterating over it seems to be built in.

In [15]: timeit.timeit('tuple(t)','t=tuple(range(1000))')
Out[15]: 0.2980363769966061

In [16]: timeit.timeit('tuple(iter(t))','t=tuple(range(1000))')
Out[16]: 10.465970789002313

But it sounds like you might be looking for the "collections.namedtuple" class

Comment: Hmmm, so you need pick up attributes from your instance, right? https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#tuple According to the doc, it seems iteration is the only way to do that. By calling `tuple` you still get performance gain as compared with `list`.

Comment: What should happen if you call `list(a)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The built-in `tuple()` is not designed as a point of customization for your classes. As far as I know there is no customization point for conversion to tuple.

So instead you've used a designed point of customization, the `iter()` built-in and corresponding `__iter__` method. That's fine as far as it goes, but it does both less and more than you want:

- More because it allows *anyone* to iterate over your object, not just `tuple()`.
- Less because although `tuple` detects the case its argument is a tuple, it doesn't detect the case it returns a tuple-iterator from `__iter__`. So as you've seen it copies the tuple.

Since there is no way to directly customize the effect of passing your object to `tuple()` (unlike `iter()` or `len()` or many others), you basically can't use the `tuple()` function as the way to access `self.my_tuple`. All you can do is make it return a copy.

Based on your comment:

> I have several attributes for instance a.b, a.c, a.d and I would like
>   to be able to do tuple(a) to get (b,c,d)

You could perhaps make use of `collections.namedtuple`:

```
class A(collections.namedtuple('A', 'b c d')):
    # whatever methods you need
```

Of course this means those attributes of `A` are immutable, so if that's not what you want then it's not helpful.

Answer (score 2):

From the various comments your question raised, my suggestion allows to get a tuple from the attributes of an object:

```
>>> class Tupleable(object):
    def __iter__(self):
        return (v for v in self.__dict__.itervalues())

>>> class A(Tupleable):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

>>> a = A(2, 'e')
>>> tuple(a)
(2, 'e')
```

ALL attributes are shown, so if you want to exclude some attributes this is not the good direction, but this could fit your needs.